# Tailwind CSS missing some functionality on one of two projects

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, webpack, tailwind-css

I inherited two tailwind projects and one of them works well while the other is missing functionality like inline styles.  It completely ignores attributes like text-[#000000] and various other quirks that work on the sister project.  Both are running the same version and I think it must be related to webpack somehow, which isn't my specialty. Looking for ideas on where I can troubleshoot this issue.

I tried updating PostCSS, verified Tailwind version, matched tailwind.config between both projects.

Thank you

Comment: The class you listed uses arbitrary values, which are a Tailwind 3.x feature. Are both projects on Talwind 3.x ?
If you think it's a webpack issue, it would be useful to share your web pack configs.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm using 3.2.4 on both installations.  Feature works on one project but not the other.  I'll try to post web pack config.